# To calculate number the of games, given the final score of the game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose you have a game (a game is defined as a set of 275 matches). In each match Player 1 gets a point if he wins and Player 2 gets 10 points if he wins. Let the final score of the game be $267:80$ (Player 1 score: Player 2 score). So, Player 1 won 267 times and Player 2 only 8 times. The first question is: what is the possible number of games that could have ended with a given final score? The second is: what is the number of games ending with a given final score where Player 1 was leading throughout the game (except for the very beginning, where the score is $0:0$)? And in the end you can therefore calculate the probability of Player 1 leading throughout the game, that ended in a given score under the assumption that all sequences of games are equally likely. The question is from the Russian olympiad "Я профессионал"("I am a pro") for university students, in which I participated this year, but was unable to solve this problem, which I memorized and translated into English. The answer to the first question is $\binom{275}{8}$ as pointed out by the comments and for the second question we consider the expression $$\binom{275}{8} - \left|\bigcup_{k=1}^{8}{A_k}\right|$$
Where $A_k$ is the event of Player 2 winning at least $k$ times in the first $10k$ matches.
$$\binom{275}{8} - \left|\bigcup_{k=1}^{8}{A_k}\right|=\binom{275}{8} -\left( \sum_{k=1}^{8}{|A_k|}-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq8}{|A_i\cap A_j|}+\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq8}{|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|}-\dots+(-1)^{7}|A_1\cap\dots\cap A_8|\right).$$
So,$\sum_{k=1}^{8}{|A_k|}=\sum_{k=1}^{8}{\sum_{i=1}^{8}{\binom{10k}{i}}}=47038748632$. Then $$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq8}{|A_i\cap A_j|}=|A_1\cap A_2|+\dots+|A_1\cap A_8|+|A_2\cap A_3|+\dots+ |A_2\cap A_8|+|A_3\cap A_4|+\dots |A_3\cap A_8|+|A_4\cap A_5|+\dots+|A_4\cap A_8|+|A_5\cap A_6|+\dots+|A_5\cap A_8|+|A_6\cap A_7|+\dots+|A_6\cap A_8|+|A_7\cap A_8|$$
If we take for instance $|A_1\cap A_2|$, then I guess $|A_1\cap A_2|=|A_1|^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{8}{\binom{10}{i}}\right)^2=1012^2$. So, $|A_1\cap A_3|=|A_1||A_2|=1012\cdot 263949$. My logic for $|A_1\cap A_3|$ is that we need to have both at least 1 win in the 1st 10 and at least 3 in the 1st 30 matches, but that is the same as saying at least 1 win in the 1st 10 and at least 2 in the last 20. However, I am not sure about my reasoning, can anyone point out how to calculate these $|A_i\cap A_j|$ terms correctly in this case? The same question goes for  $|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|$ terms. If I figure out how to do them, the second question reduces to computations and the overall problem would be solved. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Clarification requested: "The first question is: what is the possible number of games that could have ended with a given final score? " : If no games can end in a tie, and the 1st player had to win exactly $267$ games, and the 2nd player had to win exactly $8$ games, then why isn't the answer to this first question immediately seen to be $(267 + 8) = 275~$?

Comment: Re previous comment, are you instead asking how many different ways that the [player-2] wins might have been distributed among the $275$ games?  If so, then wouldn't this simply be $\displaystyle \binom{275}{8},$ which represents the number of distinct ways of selecting $8$ objects from a group of $275$ objects?  Unclear what is being asked for here.

Comment: @user2661923 Sorry, a game here is defined by a set of 275 matches, so we need to calculate the number of possible permutations in these matches in the first question, so $275!$. My problem is the second question here

Comment: Clarification requested: What is the $(275!)$ figure supposed to represent?  There are only $\displaystyle \binom{275}{8}$ ways that the $8$ [player-2] wins can be distributed among the $275$ games played.  So, I am having a hard time attaching any significance to the $(275!)$ expression.

Comment: Re previous comment, another way of saying the same thing is: $(275!)$ would seem to be appropriate only if you have $275$ different objects and you had to be concerned about where each of these objects occurs in the sequence of length $275$.  However, here, you only have two different types of objects, either a [player-1] win or a [player-2] win.  So, I don't see how $(275 !)$ can relate to anything here.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, sorry, you are right. $\binom{275}{8}$

Comment: Normally, for a problem like this, there seems to be $3$ distinct approaches: [1] the direct approach, [2] recursion, or [3] [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  I recommend Inclusion-Exclusion.  Let $A_k$ represent a distribution where there are at least $k$ [player-2] wins among the first $(10k)$ games $~: ~k \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.  Let $|S|$ denote the number of elements in a set $S$.  Then you would want $$\binom{275}{8} - |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots A_8|.$$

Comment: Re previous comment, as an alternative definition of $A_k$, you might define $A_k$ to be the number of distributions where the $k$-th [player-2] win occurred at some point in the first $(10k)$ games.

Comment: Personally, I surmise that you haven't received training in this problem, so this problem is not a homework problem.  My instinct is to therefore simply hand you the answer.  However, mathSE protocol, which I disagree with in this instance, says no.  For more info, re the protocol, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Normally, for a problem like this, I would automatically use my PC to **sanity-check** whatever formula that I derived, via a brute force simulation.  Here, this may be problematic, since (my PC, for one) balks at much greater than $(10)^8$ simulations $\displaystyle \left[ \text{i.e. consider} ~\binom{275}{8}\right].$  One approach is to derive a formula for [player-2] win $~= 5$ points, with [player-one] winning (for example) $40$ games, and [player-2] winning $5$ games.  Your PC is more likely to be able to routinely handle a brute force simul of $\displaystyle \binom{45}{5}$ iterations.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you, this is indeed not a homework assignment. I am trying to solve the problem now. Is my reasoning correct? I suppose that the ways of Player 2 winning once in the 1st 10 games is $\binom{10}{1}$, winning 2 times in the 1st 10 games is $\binom{10}{2}$ and so on until $\binom{10}{8}$, and now we sum all of them, then do the same for the 1st $20, 30, \cdots , 80$ ?

Comment: No, that is no good, because the events of (for example) at least $1$ win in the first $10$, and at least $2$ wins in the first $20$ **are not disjoint** events.  Hence Inclusion-Exclusion, which you have to **study**.

Comment: The alternative approach is to edit your question to **significantly** improve its quality, with respect to the protocol article that I linked to.  This would then allow a mathSE reviewer to hand you the answer.  Note that your analysis, question details, ... belong in the edited question, not the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\binom{275}{8} - \left|\bigcup_{k=1}^{8}{A_k}\right|$$
> Where $A_k$ is the event of Player 2 winning at least $k$ times in the first $10k$ matches.

In the comments, I suggested using Inclusion-Exclusion, which is represented by the above excerpt from the original posting.  However, I found the enumeration to be so ugly that I will instead use a direct approach.

For $k \in \{1,2,\cdots,8\}$, let $x_k$ denote the exact number of player-2 wins that occur in games $[10k - 9]$ through $[10k]$ inclusive.  In order for the 2nd player to be even or ahead at some point, one of the following constraints must be satisfied:

- $x_1 \geq 1.$
- $x_1 + x_2 \geq 2.$
- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \geq 3.$
- $\cdots$
- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_8 \geq 8.$

This means that in order for the first player to always be ahead, **all** of the following constraints must be satisfied:

$\textbf{Set of 8 Constraints}$

- $x_1 < 1.$
- $x_1 + x_2 < 2.$
- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 < 3.$
- $\cdots$
- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_8 < 8.$

So, how can the above analysis be used to enumerate the number of pertinent distributions?

First, you must obtain a complete list of all ordered $8$-tuples that satisfy the $8$ constraints above.  Then, for each such $8$-tuple, the enumeration is

$$\binom{10}{x_1} \times \binom{10}{x_2} \times \cdots \times \binom{10}{x_8} \times \binom{275 - 80}{8 - [x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_8]}. \tag1 $$

Suppose that the number of distributions where player-1 is always ahead is $S$.  Then, in order to compute $S$,
you must use the formula in (1) above to attach a number to each $8$-tuple that satisfies all of the $8$ constraints.

Then, $S$ equals the sum of all of these *attached* numbers.  Then, as indicated in the original posting, the probability of player-1 always being ahead is

$$\frac{S}{\binom{275}{8}}.$$

---

I know of no easy way of identifying all of the satisfying $8$-tuples, except by writing a simple computer program.  Such a computer program could then easily apply the formula in (1) above to each of the satisfying $8$-tuples.  This implies that such a computer program can routinely compute $S$.

For what it's worth, the manual enumeration of each satisfying $8$-tuple will look like:

$(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ 
$(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)$ 
$(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2)$ 
$\cdots$ 
$(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7)$

$(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)$ 
$(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)$ 
$(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2)$ 
$\cdots$ 
$(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,6)$

$(0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0)$ 
$(0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1)$ 
$\cdots$ 
$(0,0,0,0,0,0,2,5).$

$\cdots$ 
$(0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0).$ 
$(0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1).$

$(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)$ 
$\cdots$ 
$(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1).$